# SparkJava - Case sensitive endpoints

Tags: java, http, spark-java

I have a java code which serves http endpoints using SparkJava (http://sparkjava.com/).

Endpoints are generated like that:

```
 get("/xxx/yyy", (request, response) -> {
        ...
        return SOMETHING_TO_RETURN
 });
```

With that approach I have a problem:
let's say I have an endpoint defined: '/api/status/car' ,
but users sometimes invoke '/api/status/**CAR**' instead. So the problem is with case sensitive of url defined like that.

Now I have to fix it somehow: **make that case insensitive.**
I had take a look on filters (e.g. 'before'), but I can't modify request url (toLowerCase) I believe.

So the main question is: With defining endpoints using that approach, how can I modify request url to be lowercase, or to say sparkjava that urls should be mapped with case insensitive mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URLs (except the domain name part) might always be case-sensitive. It's up to the server to decide and therefore the user can never know. You can read about it more in [W3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/htmlweb.html).

One approach to solve your problem could be using **request params**:

```
get("/api/status/:carParam", (request, response) -> {
  if (request.params(":carParam").equalsIgnoreCase("car")) {
    return SOMETHING_TO_RETURN;
  }
});
```

If you have more routes under `/api/status/` except `car` then you should rename `:carParam` to a more generic name like `:param` and then inside the handler body, you'd check this query param and return the right return value accordingly. For example:

```
get("/api/status/:param", (request, response) -> {
  if (request.params(":param").equalsIgnoreCase("car")) {
    return SOMETHING_TO_RETURN_CAR;
  } else if (request.params(":param").equalsIgnoreCase("passenger")) {
    return SOMETHING_TO_RETURN_PASSENGER;
  }
});
```